# how to refresh block in twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

javascript code that call the controller every 5 sec

```
                           $.post('{{path('nb_invitation')}}',
                             {data: '1'},
                             function(response){
                                 if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
                                     alert('yes');
                                 }
                             }, "json");
```

the code:

my notificationIv.html

```
{% block notificationIv -%}  
    // content
    {% endblock %}
```

rooting

```
 nb_invitation:
        path:     /communaute/nb_invitation
        defaults: { _controller: communauterBundle:notificationIv:nb_invitation }
```

controller

```
public function nb_invitationAction(Request $request){
     return  $this->render('communauterBundle:notificationIv:notificationIv.html.twig');
    }
```

index.html

```
  {% block notificationIv -%}
         {{ render(controller('communauterBundle:notificationIv:nb_invitation')) }}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: i cant see the change in my block the block doesn't get the new data

Comment: Is this javascript code in external .js (ncluded) or inline in twig .thml file in <script> block.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post('{{path('nb_invitation')}}',
   {data: '1'},
   function(response){
          if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
              $("#notification_identifier").html(response.data)     // or whatever you return 
          }
}, "json");
```

As floren said you are confuse, code above is an example using jquery, just only need to define an id (or a class) to notificaction container so you can update contents..some like

```
{% block notificationIv -%}  
  <div id="notification_identifier"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the use of JS and PHP - they are not equivalent in a html page. Your

```
{{ render(controller('communauterBundle:notificationIv:nb_invitation')) }}
```

is not going to "refresh" itself just because you make an ajax call to the controller. If you really want this to refresh then maybe something like

### index.html

```
<div id="alert"></div>
```

### controller

```
return JsonResponse(array('message' => $message ))
```

i'm not familiar with jQuery ajax syntax but basically you make a GET ajax and replace the html value in your div#alert with whatever your ajax returns. Something like (correct me for syntax)

### script.js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{path('nb_invitation')}}",//even though you can use js routing in symfony, much cleaner
}).done(function(response) {
    $.getElementById('alert').html(response.message)
});
```

I know syntax is not exact but that would be the idea